# UISlider not smooth

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uislider, smoothing

I'm developing an iPad app and using a lot of UISliders. But when I test the app on an iPad 1, the sliders are not responding very smooth. I'm not doing anything when the value of the slider changes. Only when the slider is released (touch up inside/outside).

Also the touch up inside/outside method is not always called.

Is this a common problem on iPad 1 or is it caused by my app?

Comment: Did you tested the app on other devices?

Comment: No, only on iPad 1 and iOs-simulator.

Comment: If you use 'a lot of UISliders' it could be related with poor A4 CPU performances. What do you mean with a lot?

Comment: There are screens with 5 sliders in it.

Comment: I am also having the same problem but its works fine in ipad2

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am facing the same. Please Help.!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an animation with slider, you should use `[slider setValue:0.5 animated:YES]` method of `UISlider` instance.

Comment: That's not what I meant, sorry. I'm not moving the slider programmatically. They don't always respond smooth when I'm changing the value by sliding the slider.

Comment: OK, may be the difference between min and max values is to small and the jumper stays just in nearest possible position...

Comment: The difference between min and max is most of the time quite high. There are sliders where the min value is 0 and the max value is 500.000 and they're having the same problem.